# Receive feedback/email on new specific tag question?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, notifications, notification-bar

Is it possible to receive an email or some sort of notification when a new questions pops out from a specific tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create filters of questions by tag or site at [StackExchange.com/filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters). You can subscribe to email updates, sent either every 15 minutes, four hours or 24 hours. For example,

[image: my CoffeeScript filter, for example]

There are also third-party apps available on [StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/) that serve this purpose. For example, I use [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-os-x) which notifies me almost immediately when a new question is posted with one of my tags.

Comment: Hmm, apparently you don't get the "Other answer was posted" warning on mobile.

Comment: @John - This is unrelated to the "Other answer was posted" notification. Filters are for questions, not for answers.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: He's remarking that he didn't receive that warning for his answer to this question.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Ah, now I understand.  Took me a minute... :/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is possible with [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/25893/my-filter-2). Make a filter for your tag, and there is an option to have email you with new questions.